# Using an EGPU to bypass faulty D300 in Mac Pro

Tags: mac-pro

We have a 2013 Mac Pro with High Sierra and the dreaded D300 graphics card that suffers from the lock up issue that plagued these machines.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use an external GPU box with this thing and completely bypass/disable the D300 so that we can use the (expensive) computer for more than a few minutes at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2013 8 core with d300 and when running the “yes” command line terminal test I get lockups and beach balls, even with a freshly installed system. Doesn’t happen in safe mode. I then connected an eGPU (RX 580 8GB in an Akitio Node) and no lockups. Your mileage may vary but works for me.